# Null object when deserializing JSON Data in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to convert a big JSON data to C#.

The json, has a root object and in that root object it has over 20 data types and 3 other objects.

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to handle the JSON deserializtion

---

My Approach 1: Got null ClassA inside RootObject

Created a 4 classes. RootObjectClass and ClassA/B/C/D

```
var root = new RootObjectClass();
root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectClass>(jsonContent);
```

Approach 2: got null all data types and the 3 classes

Created a 3 classes. ClassA and ClassB/C/D

```
var classA = ClassA();
classA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(jsonContent);
```

---

Class Structure:

RootObject:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public ClassA someClassA { get; set; }
    }
```

Class A:

```
public class ClassA
{
    //20 different data types.
    public ClassB classB { get; set; }
    public ClassC classC { get; set; }
    public ClassD classD { get; set; }
}
```

Class B, C, D:

```
public class ClassB/C/D
    {
        //10 different data types.
    }
```

---

Json Data: Example version

```
{
  "classA": {
    "format": "some format",
    "classB": {
      "num": "11",
      "word": "some word"
    },
    "classC": {
      "num1": "1111",
      "word": "some string"
    },
    "classD": {
      "seomString": "some string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well the property names in the JSON are all `objectA`, `objectB` etc... whereas your property names in C# are `classA`, `classB` etc. How did you expect that to work?

Comment: you  should deserialize the RootObject and then assign each nested object independly

Comment: @Jon They are the same name just when I wrote that sample I forgot to match the names

Comment: Many json parsers have the ability to change the name of the corresponding fields, for example a property named "Foo" may become "Bar" in the json object. Often this is made decorating the properties with attribute. Read [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) for a wider look.

Comment: Could you show us the exact structure of all the classes?

Comment: @MartDavious in your edit there is still a mistake: the properties are named "ClassB" etc but the json field is "classB"... that's an uppercase difference...

Comment: @BRHAIM I will try that

Comment: @Kraus The classes contain only string, double and int and the json also contains the same types.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Thanks I missed that. I edit my question to match what I have in code. The problem was that my root object didn't match the json. Ex: I had ClassA someClassA {get;set;} but changing it to ClassA classA {get;set;} fixed it

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah you were right!. The names where differ in my code!

Comment: just use http://json2csharp.com/, paste in your JSON or part of it that's a representative sample and it will generate the deserialization classes for you. Then use those classes or compare them to yours to work out what's wrong with your approach.

Comment: All of this is why you should do the diagnostic work required to provide a [mcve] before you post.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reference! I'll keep that in mind.